# Javascript: access object scope members within higher order function

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, higher-order-functions

Domain model

```
var Question = function(text, answerType){
    this.id = 0
    this.text = text;
}

var Form = function(){
    this.questions = [] 
    this.addQuestion = function(question){
        question.id = this.questions.length + 1
        this.questions.push(question)
    }
}
```

Renders a Form

```
var FormRenderer = function(){
    this.wrapperSelector = "#wrapper"
    this.render = function(form){
       // how to access renderQuestion member of FormRenderer within the higher-order function?
       $(form.questions).each( function(){ **this.renderQuestion(form, this) }**) 
    }

    this.renderQuestion = function(form, question){
        var questionDomId = "question" + question.id

        var questionText = '<input type="text" size="75" name="questionText" value="'+ question.text +'" /><br/><br/><br/>'
        var questionWrapper  = "<div id='" + questionDomId + "'>" + questionText + "</div>"

        // how do i access wrapperSelector member of FormRender when renderQuestion is called as higher-order function?
        **$(this.wrapperSelector).append(questionWrapper)** 
    }
}
```

Client code

```
var q1= new Question("question1", "Text Box")
var form = new Form()
form.addQuestion(q1)

var formRenderer = new FormRenderer()
formRenderer.render(form)
```

The question is the same as the title. I have asked help for a specific example above with Javascript comments. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please note that `each` is the higher-order-function, not `renderQuestion`. Btw, this looks to me like inappropriate usage of `each` - just use a for-loop and you don't have those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the object like so:

```
var FormRenderer = function(){
    this.wrapperSelector = "#wrapper"
    this.render = function(form){
       $(form.questions).each( this.renderQuestion) ;
    }

   var self = this; // <--------------- 

   this.renderQuestion = function(form, question){
        var questionDomId = "question" + question.id

        var questionText = '<input type="text" size="75" name="questionText" value="'+ question.text +'" /><br/><br/><br/>'
        var questionWrapper  = "<div id='" + questionDomId + "'>" + questionText + "</div>"

        // now use self instead of this
        $(self.wrapperSelector).append(questionWrapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, the `form` parameter is the array index.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent object instance in `this` inside the member functions, by calling them like below.

if `object` is your instance, and `func` is a member function inside which you want `this` to be your instance itself, then you can call the member function as:

```
obj.func.call(obj, <params>);
```

instead of

```
object.func(<params>);
```

---

In your case, this would be:

```
var fR = new FormRenderer(<params>);
...
fR.renderQuestion.call(fR, <params>);
```

Your `renderQuestion` can use `this` just like outside. i.e.

```
var FormRenderer = function(){
    this.wrapperSelector = "#wrapper"
    ...
    this.renderQuestion = function(form, question){

        // this refers to the object itself, so you can call        
        $(this.wrapperSelector).append(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fR.renderQuestion.call(fR, <params>);` would be absolutely equal to `fR.renderQuestion(<params>);`. However, that was not the question - the OP's problem is that `this` does not point to the instance when the method is fed into `jQuery.each`

Answer (score 0):

Had to restructure a little to solve the problem based on input from Pumbaa80 and Bergi. Thanks for your answers.

```
var FormRenderer = function(){
    this.render = function(form){
        var formEventHandler = new FormEventHandler(form)
        $(form.questions).each(new RenderQuestion(formEventHandler).render)
    }

    RenderQuestion = function(formEventHandler){
        this.formEventHandler = formEventHandler
        this.wrapperSelector = "#wrapper"
        var self = this
        this.render = function(index, question){
            var questionDomId = "question" + question.id

            // generate elements
            var questionText = '<input type="text" size="75" name="questionText" value="'+ question.text +'" /><br/>'
            var questionWrapper  = "<div id='" + questionDomId + "'>" + questionText + "</div>"

            // append to dom
            $(self.wrapperSelector).append(questionWrapper)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiating a new instance of the local `RenderQuestion` each time `render` is called seems useless. Why don't you just pass a function which does those things?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) - it changes the `this` reference to something unusual. You could use [ES 5.1 `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and the normal [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```
FormRenderer.prototype.render = function(form) {
    form.questions.forEach(this.renderQuestion.bind(this, form));
};
```

I'd recommend to use a classical for-loop, which is much easier to read and faster than any higher-order-things:

```
FormRenderer.prototype.render = function(form) {
    for (var i=0; i<form.questions.length; i++)
        this.renderQuestion(form, form.questions[i]);
};
```

If you really wanted/needed to use `jQuery.each`, you'd need to preserve the reference to the current `FormRenderer` instance (`this`) in a variable:

```
FormRenderer.prototype.render = function(form) {
    var renderer = this;
    $.each(form.questions, function(i) {
        renderer.renderQuestion(form, this);
    });
};
```